# Is using observer pattern as a notifier same as using Thread.join?

Tags: java

Is using a join to wait until a Thread has finished the same as using the an observer to notify the calling thread class when the thread has finised ?

```
Using join - 

public class Reader {

    Thread t = new Thread(new ReadContent());
    t.start();
    t.join();
    System.out.println("Thread has finished");

        public class ReadContent() implements Runnable{
        }

        public void run() {
            readContentURL(); 
        }
}

/*****************************************************************************/
    Using observer - 


public interface ReadContentListener{

    public void contentRead();

}


 public class Reader implements ReadContentListener {

    Thread t = new Thread(new ReadContent(this));
    t.start();

    pubic void contentRead(){
     System.out.println("Thread has finished");
    }

        public class ReadContent implements Runnable{

        public ReadContent(ReadContentListener readContentListener) {
            this.readContentListener = readContentListener;
        }

        public void run() {
            readContentURL(); 
            this.readContentListener.contentRead();
        }
}


/*************************************************************/

    public GenericScreenAnimation(String nextScreen, Thread genericWorkerThread)
{

         this.genericWorkerThread = genericWorkerThread;
         this.genericWorkerThread.start();
         initialise();
         try {
            this.genericWorkerThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ScreenController.displayNextScreen(nextScreen);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same. I'd say using join() in this context is not good programming practice - why use Threads otherwise? You're essentially turning what is an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one.

Using the Observer pattern is Asynchronous and, if you're doing this in UI code, is what I would use to prevent the GUI locking up (well, maybe use a SwingWorker or something like that, but the same principle).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using join.  When used correctly it can be absolutely appropriate.  Now if a person simply passes in a runnable to a thread starts the thread and immediately joins on it then yes that is wrong.

Comment: @John V - you're absolutely right. I didn't mean to say using join() in general is wrong. I've edited my answer to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Ive added some more code to original question - GenericScreenAnimation. The method initialise() paints a GIF animation while genericWorkerThread is running. When genericWorkerThread has finished, I want to display a new screen. Is ok to use .join in this case ?

Comment: @user470184 I think it would be OK to use join, looking at your actual code. I just don't think calling start() on a thread and then immediately calling join() is good practice!

Answer (score 4):

The observer pattern is about notifying other **objects**, not other threads.
Your ReadContentListener will be notified **in the reading thread** if the reading has finished.
The original thread during this will continue it's own work (or finish, if there is none).

Using Thread.join makes the original thread simply block until the reading thread is finished.
You would use this normally never directly after `.start()`, but only if you have other things to do on the original thread, which should be done in parallel to the reading. Calling this directly after `.start()` is (for the effects) equivalent to doing the reading *on the original thread*.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is the same, as no more statements will execute in thread, but there are points:

- when `join` returns it's guaranteed that thread finished, but when notifying observer thread is still running
- after `join` you are in main (or parent) thread, with observer you are in thread that is going to finish.

Comment: Ive added some more code to original question - GenericScreenAnimation. The method initialise() paints a GIF animation while genericWorkerThread is running. When genericWorkerThread has finished, I want to display a new screen. Is ok to use .join in this case ?

Comment: I usually prefer using observers in such case, I agree with @PhillSacre. Because using `join` you just block one of threads, and using observer is fully asynchronous.